# Listbox updating

Tags: python, tkinter

When I run this it only displays the percent after it's done downloading so is there a way to make it display as it downloads it?

```
listbox = Listbox(Admin)
listbox.grid(row=19, column=9)
def download0(runums, song):

    chunks = 10000
    dat = ''
    runum = runums.replace(' ', '%20')
    url = runum
    down = urlopen(url)
    downso = 0
    tota = down.info().getheader('Content-Length').strip()
    tota = int(tota)
    while 1:
        a = down.read(chunks)
        downso += len(a)

        if not a:
            break
        dat += a
        percent = float(downso) / tota
        percent = round(percent*100, 1)

        sys.stdout.write(str(percent))
        sys.stdout.flush()

        sys.stdout.write("\b"*4)
        listbox.insert(END, percent)
```

Comment: Easiest way is usually to put the downloader into some thread or use some event based downloading based on select() (e.g. the twisted ones) to keep the event loop alive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tkinter event loop (started by `mainloop()`) runs on a single thread. It spins, reacting to events (e.g. mouse clicks), repainting widgets, and so on.    When a button is clicked to start the download, control is passed to your `download0()` function. Until control returns to the event loop, no widgets will redraw unless you tell them to.

So while the download is in progress you need to tell the widget to redraw itself:

```
listbox.insert(END, percent)
listbox.update_idletasks()
```

Comment: You should  **definitely not** use `update`. Instead, use `update_idletasks`. Why? `update` could potentially respond to user events. If those user events call this same function again you'll have problems. `update_idletasks` is safe because it only responses to "idle" events such as redrawing the screen.